# d3.js change circle radius on mouse events

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have circles that I've drawn in d3.js v5. I'm getting the mouse over events as expected, and I can log stuff to the console and everything looks right. The only part that isn't working is when I try and set the radius to be larger. The radius size isn't changing.

```
function handleMouseOver(d, i) {   
    console.log("over ", d, i);
    console.log("this", this)
    d3.select(this).attr({
        r: 8
    });
}

function handleMouseOut(d, i) {   
    console.log("out ", d, i);
    d3.select(this).attr({
        r: 4
    });
}
```

Here is the part where the circles are drawn.

```
linesAndDots
    .selectAll(".data-circle")
    .data(d=>d.values)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "data-circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return xScale(d.date);
        })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return yScale(d.measurement)
     })
     .on("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
     .on("mouseout", handleMouseOut);
```

Here is the small reproducible demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/23etevpozYBTpXdH

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `handleMouseOver` and `handeMouseOut` as following:

```
function handleMouseOver(d, i) {       
    d3.select(this).transition()
        .duration(1)
        .attr("r", 20);
}

function handleMouseOut(d, i) {   
    d3.select(this).transition()
        .duration(1)
        .attr("r", 4);
}
```

You can't change the styling using just the `.attr` attribute, you'll need to define a `transition()` ([docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition)).

Updated snippet: [Click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1PnRHlCZtMNOpwA5)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code you are setting r like this

```
.attr("r", 5)
```

but than you are using

```
.attr({ r: 8 });
```

Maybe you need to use this

```
d3.select(this).attr("r", 8);
```

Never use d3js just a though